# Spatialite: how to add column with reference key?

Tags: spatialite, spatialite-gui

I'm quite new to Spatialite but I need to build a small geographical database. I created a table and now I need to add a new column to it and to associate to this column a foreign key. Is it possible in any way?

I found out the code for SQLite, but not for Spatialite:

```
alter table Table1 add NewColumn integer references ExternalTable (id) on delete cascade
```

I've tried something that sounds good to me:

```
ALTER TABLE Routes
ADD COLUMN category INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT fk_routes_cat
    FOREIGN KEY (category)
    REFERENCES Vocabulary (id);
```

But Spatialite-gui gave an error:

> SQL error: "near "FOREIGN": syntax error"

Comment: Have you enabled foreign keys already https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html? SpatiaLite is normal SQLite database with no special tricks.

Comment: @user30184 I'm working in spatialite-gui: it silently enables foreign keys any time a new db is connected

Comment: By reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884818/how-do-i-add-a-foreign-key-to-an-existing-sqlite-3-6-21-table your original plan should work. I tested with spatialite-gui and  `ALTER TABLE Routes ADD COLUMN category INTEGER REFERENCES Vocabulary (id);` with success.

Comment: @user30184 You're definitely right! It doesn't work with "Foreign Key" but withe "References" it does... may I ask what is the difference?

Comment: SQLite just does not support "alter column add constraint" http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html.